# Hide undefined values in select-list with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've displayed select-list as below:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="primaryEmail" ng-options="e.email for e in emails" ng-change="changePrimaryEmail()"></select>
```

$scope.emails is bound to textboxes using ng-repeat.

```
$scope.emails=[{"id":1,"customerID":1,"email":"a@test.com","toDelete":0,"isPrimary":false},{"id":10,"customerID":1,"email":"b@test.com","toDelete":0,"isPrimary":false},{"id":11,"customerID":1,"email":"c@test.com","toDelete":0,"isPrimary":true},{"customerID":1,"toDelete":0}];

<div ng-repeat="em in emails">
<input type="email" ng-model="em.email" />
</div>
```

When I add new textbox, dropdown should not display its value if it's undefined.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom filter as follows:

```
ng-options="e.email for e in (emails | hideUndefined)"
```

**Filter:**

```
app.filter('hideUndefined', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var filtered_items = [];

        //iterate over all emails
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            //if not undefined, add to filtered_items array
            if(items[i].email !== undefined) {
                filtered_items.push(items[i])
            }
        }
        return filtered_items;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use `emails` instead of `$scope.emails` like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="model.primaryEmail" ng-options="e.email for e in emails" ng-change="changePrimaryEmail()"></select>

<div ng-repeat="em in emails">
<input type="email" ng-model="em.email" />
</div>
```